# Print a multiline text document

Tags: java

I am having an issue with my code not printing out all of what is in a text document. My assignment is to take what is in a .txt file and put in a new .txt file I guess you could say "fancier."

This is the text file I am given.

> Thomas Smith 3 2.25 44
>
> Kim Johnson 2 55.60 35
>
> John Doe 33 2.90 21
>
> Karen Java 1 788.99 65

This is the "fancy" output I need(only It needs to output all of them).

> The first name is: Thomas
>
> The last name is: Smith
>
> The total number of items bought is: 3
>
> The customer's total is: 6.75
>
> The customer's total rounded (cast) is: 6
>
> The age of the customer is: 44

I think I have just been staring at it so long I'm just over looking it...

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("customer.txt"));
    
    double options;
    System.out.println("How would you like to input your data?\n1 Input information from customer.txt\n2 Input information from the keyboard.");
    options = console.nextDouble();
    
    
    if (options == 1){
        
        //Variable to store first name
        String firstName;
        //Variable to store last name
        String lastName;
                
        //Variable to store how many items bought
        int itemsBought;
        //Variable to store the price per item
        double itemPrice; 
        //Variable to store their age
        int age;
        
        
        while (inFile.hasNext()){
            
            
            //Gets the first name
            firstName = inFile.next();
            //Gets the last name
            lastName = inFile.next();
            
            //Gets number of items bought
            itemsBought = inFile.nextInt();
            //Gets the price per item
            itemPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            // Gets their age
            age = inFile.nextInt(); 
            

            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("programOutputFile.txt");
        
            outFile.println("The customers first name is: " + firstName); 
            outFile.println("The customers last name is: " + lastName);
            outFile.println("The customer bought " + (int)itemsBought + " items.");
            outFile.println("The customers total is " + itemPrice);
            outFile.println("The total cost rounded " + (int)itemPrice);
            outFile.println("The customers age is: " + (int)age);

            
            outFile.close();
            
        }   
    
        
    }
    else if (options == 2) {
        
        String firstname;
        String lastname;
        int items = 0;
        double price = 0;
        int age1 = 0;
        
        int counter; //loop control variable
        counter = 0;
    
        int limit; //store the number of items
        System.out.print("Enter the number of entries you have "); //Line 1
        limit = console.nextInt(); //Line 2
        
        
        
    while (counter < limit) {
        
        // It is asking for the user to input their first name 
         
                    System.out.println("Please tell me what is your first name? ");
                    firstname = console.next();
                    
                    // It is asking for the user to input their last name
                    System.out.println("What is your last name? ");
                    lastname = console.next();
                    
                    // It is asking for the number of items they purchased
                    System.out.println("How many items did your purchase? ");
                    items = console.nextInt();
                    
                    // Here it is asking for the total price they paid

                    System.out.println("What was the cost of each item? ");
                    price = console.nextDouble();
                    
                    System.out.println("How old are you? ");
                    age1 = console.nextInt();
                    
                    double total = items * price;
        
            
        counter++;
            
        if (counter != 0){
            //Outputs the length of Firstname
            System.out.println("The name is " + firstname.length() + " letters in your first name.");
                            
            //Outputs the first letter of LastName
            System.out.println("The first letter of your last name is: " + lastname.charAt(0));
        
            //Outputs the number of items bought
            System.out.println("You bought " + items + " items.");
            
            //Outputs Price
            System.out.println("Your total price was " + total);
            
            //Outputs the Price as a int number
            System.out.println("Your total price rounded is " + (int)total);
            
            //Outputs the age
            System.out.println("They are " + age1 + " years old.");
            
            
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("programOutputFile.txt");
            
            //Outputs the information given above into a .txt file
            outFile.println("The customers first name is: " + firstname); 
            outFile.println("The customers last name is: " + lastname);
            outFile.println("The customer bought " + (int)items + " items.");
            outFile.println("The customers total is " + total);
            outFile.println("The total cost rounded " + (int)total);
            outFile.println("The customers age is: " + (int)age1);
            
            outFile.close();
        
                
            
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid. Please try again.");
    
    
            
        }
    
    
    }
    
    
    inFile.close();
    
    
    
    
}
```

As of right now it will print out Karen Java's line instead of Karen, John, Kim, and Thomas's. I have option 2 finished but again I am having the same problem of it only prints out the last input.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You reopen the file in your loop each time you write. This has the effect of overwrite any previous contents of the file (the previous output you just wrote). declare `outfile` before the while loop and close it after.

Comment: As a note, he could also open the file in append mode: `PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("programOutputFile.txt"), true /* make append true */));` Then just append to it: `outFile.append(stuff)`. **DO NOT ACTUALLY DO THIS** as it would open and close and open and close again and again and you don't want that. I'm just stating that he *could*, in case he runs into a problem later where he needs to append to the file.